# GithubPages: how to enforce custom Content-Type type for any file?

Tags: content-type, github-pages

We are currently using Github pages as a simple API mock server. We put all mock files under `docs/` and simply `GET username.github.io/project/api/someAPI` to retrieve data. However, by default, the Content-Type returned by Github Pages is `application/octet-stream` instead of `application/json` for files with no extensions, therefore our frontend code throws errors when parsing the result.

I want to know is there any way to change the returned Content-Type for files with no extension on Github Page?

Comment: Same issue here, but with a MPEG-4 video coming back with either no content type (IE, Edge) or a text content type (Chrome). Video plays in Chrome, not in IE or Edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#mime-types-on-github-pages suggests this is impossible:

> you can't specify custom MIME types on a per-file or per-repository basis

From experimentation, you can create `subdir/index.json` which will cause `https://owner.github.io/repo/subdir/` to successfully  (200) serve content with type `application/json`. But `https://owner.github.io/repo/subdir` will serve a 301 redirect, which an API client may not tolerate.

Taking a hint from https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/ I tried creating `_config.yml`

```yaml
include: .htaccess
```

and `.htaccess`

```
ForceType application/json
```

without success. I also found https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5454 suggesting this is not possible.